# Add custom URL based controller to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I add a custom controller to WordPress?

For example If I enter `http://my-wp.com/custom_route` in url bar and my 
custom function gets executed.

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself? Before posting a question, ***you are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself***. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @LostKoder You can use also `global $wp;` and `$data = $wp->request;` that will do something similar than `$data = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` … If you can/want/like, please o small upvote could be nice too… Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this for example, using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the url path and then you will process it to find `'custom_route'`.

If `'custom_route'` is found, it will trigger something, like a function or some custom code:

```
$found = false;
$data = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$data = explode( '/', $data );
foreach($data as $value)
    if( 'custom_route' == $value ) ){
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
if( !empty($value) && $found ){
    // Do something here (add a function or some code
    // exec_my_custom_function();
}
```

Tested and works.